# disabling file_browser_callback on insert/edit video on tinymce 4

Tags: tinymce-4

I want to disable/hide browse button for source and other parameters in insert/edit video screen. At present I son't have back end implementation to provide the list of videos but I want this option available for insert/edit image. I am using file_browser_callback in tiny init but it looks to me that a same file_browser_callback is used to handle the browse for all the screen. Can someone suggest me a way to hide the browse for "insert/edit" video plugins but allow in "insert/edit image"?

Please check [Fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/KOeaab/1)

Comment: Which plugin are you referring to? Can you also provide the code of the init of TinyMce?

Comment: Added fiddle pl. check. I want to remove "browse" from media and link plugins but want to keep this for image plugin. Removing "file_browser_callback" code from init does this but again it does for all the plugins.

Comment: Ah that's clear, so you would like to replace these fields with default text inputs that would make it possible to insert a URL only? For this you would have to edit the plugin scripts. But wouldn't it be a good idea to just ditch the general tab of the media plugin and show only the embed tab, making video/media input only available through embed? Would be a lot clearer until you build a filemanager I think.

Comment: I have already made changes in plugin.js of both "media" and "link" plug-ins and have removed "browse" functionality but to me this doesn't look clean implementation...better if tiny would have given different callback for plugins..something like "file_browser_callback_image" , "file_browser_callback_media"  etc. Anyways thanks for your feedback.  Ditching general tab in media plugin is indeed a good idea.

Comment: Understand a bit more what you're trying :) The way the plugin's are built up and the way the callback are handled are two different things. Please see my answer below, which might help you handle the different types within the callback.

Comment: Hi.. Any fix available for this? I am using Tinymce 4.3.13 editor and facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed one `file_browser_callback` but within the callback you can target different types. In my implementation I've done the following:

```
   file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) { 
        if (type == 'file') {
            diaTitle = 'Insert link';
            browser = '/linkmanager/index.php'+'?field_id='+field_name;
        } else if (type == 'image') {
            diaTitle = 'Insert image';
            browser = '/filemanager/dialog.php?type=1&field_id='+field_name;
        }   
        tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
            title: diaTitle,
            url: browser,
            width: 860,
            height: 600
        },{
            oninsert: function(url) {
                win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = url; 
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope this can help you!

Comment: Thanks tvgemert.. I am aware of checks based on type but this again doesn't solve my purpose. Actually I don't want to see "browse" button/image probably by using this mechanism one can put some info messages. As I mentioned before the only solution I was able to make is to make changes in plugin.js file windowManager.open ..(changing type: 'filepicker' to type: 'textbox') probably this the only solution. Thanks again for your comments/answer. I have also asked this on tiny forum but no response so far.

Comment: That forum is notoriously quiet indeed. I don't think you have to look further in this specific case editing the plugin is the only way. Or searching for an alternative plugin. Personally I chose to limit media input (besides images I use a file browser for that) to entering embed code, simplifies a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE has provided a way to do this by using file_picker_types. You will need to add this to the tinymce.init, maybe right above your "file_browser_callback:"

```
file_picker_types: 'image',
```

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#file_picker_types

Comment: Seems some new dev from tiny. Will have a look how this works. Thanks